# Using Nodejs, using 'let' in console only leads to a continuation

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I try to set a variable with let I only get a continuation prompt, as if the line were unfinished.

For example if you were to type only 'var' you would get (...) that prompt, and could then continue finishing the command. This happens no matter what when using let.

```
[$] nodejs

'>' let x = 1

. . .
```

How can i finish the command? Why does it think the line isn't finished? Any advice on where to look would be appreciated, google has yielded nothing so far.

Comment: You should check your IDE setting for the code environment

Comment: Will ";" in the end help?

Comment: It looks like you might be using Ubuntu's nodejs package which is *very* old. If that's the case, you want to install node using [these instructions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) and remove the nodejs package. Once you've done that, you'll want to use `node` instead of `nodejs` at the terminal and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The **let** keyword didn’t get fully supported in nodejs until version 6.4.0. Most likely you’re using an older version of nodejs. Bump the version up to that or higher and the problem should go away.

Source [node.green](https://node.green)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. I followed Kirk Larkin's instruction, they worked. Much appreciated.
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions
His link, needed to update, sorry for the bother, thanks again.